# Why does this ACS712 current sensor have this voltage output?

Tags: voltage, current, sensor, current-measurement, proteus

I connected a 250 V, 50 Hz power supply to the [ACS712](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.pdf) 5A current sensor and set it to 9 V. I would like to know why the voltage output is 6.42 V.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's because your circuit and simulator is such that there is 6.42V output.

In real life, the ACS712 would have been either damaged by supply voltage, or it would have been damaged by shorting the mains to the input, likely tripping the mains breakers and sparks and bits of the chip flying in the air.

So if the output does not make sense, that is because none of the connections make sense either.

Comment: Well the ACS712 is internally fused but it's best not to test that with a direct connection to mains.

Answer (score 1):

Like already mentioned, you hooked it up wrongly. Your supply voltage Vcc is too high. The absolute maximum allowed Vcc per datasheet is 8V. Also you shouldn’t  connect a current sensing device in parallel as that makes no sense (no pun intended). You should always connect it in series so the current can pass through e.g. a current sensing resistor.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695994/101063) the ACS712 is being incorrectly connected in the simulation since is a *Hall-Effect-Based Linear Current Sensor IC* but is being placed directly across the mains voltage rather than in series with a load.

The ACS712 [datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.pdf)
says for the IP+ and IP– pins `Terminals for current being sampled; fused internally`, so if a real ACS712 was connected as per the simulation circuit, maybe the ACS712 fuses would open before the mains breakers tripped.  The datasheet includes a TÜV America Certificate Number, and has *Fire and Electric Shock* Specifications so presumably that failure mode has been tested to ensure the fuses open.

Another error in the simulation is that the V<sub>CC</sub> is set to 9 V, but the expected supply is in the range 4.5 V to 5.5 V (with 5 V typical).

This does highlight that the simulation may not detect a setup which will violate absolute maximum ratings and cause device failures if attempted to be created in a real circuit.